# Error building VS2015 project on TFS2015 using vNext build definition

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I added a vNext build definition on TFS2015 server to replicate my xaml builds and when I queue a build I'm getting an error that I don't understand. Here's the error:

```
Build started 12/15/2016 11:53:26 AM.
[error](2,1): Error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.
1>Project "C:\agent\_work\1\s" on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
1>C:\agent\_work\1\s(2,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.
1>Done Building Project "C:\agent\_work\1\s" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
"C:\agent\_work\1\s" (Clean target) (1) ->
C:\agent\_work\1\s(2,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.06
[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

Comment: Could you add more detailed info such as your build task configuration? `(Clean target(s)) -- FAILED` seems there are something wrong with your build agent. Could you **manually** build your project **on the build agent** successfully?

Comment: Can you share the content of your solution file?

Comment: How do you specify Project in your build definition (MSBuild or Visual Studio Build step)?